# Custom Post Type Display and works but But Blank Quick Edit

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a mystery problem.  I have successfully created a custom post type, with associated categories.  BUT, when I list the posts, the QuickEdit section does not display the title, date or any information.  It is blank and I don't know why. Can anyone see the problem?

```
//////////////////////// setup admin pages
add_action( 'init', 'mmd_client_tracking_form', 0 );                            // Add the menu
function mmd_client_tracking_form()
{
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Review Client Workouts', 'mmd_client_list' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Manage Clients', 'mmd_client_list' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'New Client', 'mmd_client_list' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Client' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Client' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Client' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'Workout Clients' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Client' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Clients' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Clients found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Clients found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Biorider Tracking'
  );


  $args = array(
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'mmdtrack_meta_box', // Register a meta box
    'labels'               => $labels,
    'description'          => 'This post type holds all posts for your directory items.',
    'public'               => true,
    'menu_position'        => 10,
    'show_ui'              => true,
    'supports'             => array( 'title' ),
    'has_archive'          => true,
    'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-media-spreadsheet',
  );
  register_post_type( 'mmdtrack', $args );  

}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// CUSTOM CATAGORY
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
add_action( 'init', 'mmd_track_taxonomies', 0 );                                  // Add the standard submenu
function mmd_track_taxonomies() {

  $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Biorider Categories', 'Biorider Categories' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Clients Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Clients Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Clients Categories' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Clients Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Clients Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Clients Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Clients Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Clients Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Clients Categories')
  );
  $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'mmdtrack_cat' )
  );

  register_taxonomy( 'mmdtrack_cat', 'mmdtrack', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'mmd_tracking_menu', 0 );                                          // Add the standard submenu
function mmd_tracking_menu()
{

add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=mmdtrack',   // Parent Slug from add_menu_page 
                 'Biorider Settings',             // Title of page
                 'Settings',                      // Menu title
                 'manage_options',                // Minimum capability to view the menu.
                 'mmd_Tracking_Settings_slug',    // Unqiue Slug Name
                 'mmd_trackingAdminPage' );    // A callback function used to display page content. 

}





//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTRIES OF MEMBER LISTINGS - MANUAL
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
function mmdtrack_meta_box(WP_Post $post)
 { 
 $prefix = 'mmdtrack';                               // Custom Post Name    
 add_meta_box($prefix, 'Set Tracking', mmdtrack_client_tracking_form);  
 }

function  mmdtrack_client_tracking_form($PostId)
{
... displaying code for metabox
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  THIS HOOKS IN TO WORDPRESS CUSTOM POST AND CHANGES THE 
//  MANAGE LIST FORM
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
add_filter('manage_mmdtrack_posts_columns', 'mmd_member_track_columns_head');
function mmd_member_track_columns_head($defaults) {

    $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_name']                    = 'Name';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_tracking_workout_count']  = 'Number of Workouts';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_memberships']             = 'Active Membershps';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_category']                = 'Categories';

    return $new_columns;
}



add_action('manage_mmdtrack_posts_custom_column', 'mmd_track_columns_content', 10, 2);
function mmd_track_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID)
{

switch($column_name)
 {  
  case 'mmd_member_name': 
      $Name  = get_the_title( $post_ID );
      echo $Name;
  break;

  case 'mmd_member_tracking_workout_count':
     $user_ID = mmd_track_FindUser($post_ID);
     echo mmd_track_GetWorkoutCnt($user_ID);
  break;

   case 'mmd_member_memberships':
     $user_ID = mmd_track_FindUser($post_ID);
     if($user_ID==0)
       echo "None";
  break;

  case 'mmd_member_category':
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_ID, 'mmdtrack_cat' );

    /* If terms were found. */
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) 
        {
        $out = array();

        /* Loop through each term, linking to the 'edit posts' page for the specific term. */
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
           {
           $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => 'mmdtrack', 'mmdtrack_cat' => $term->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
                    esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'mmdtrack_cat', 'display' ) )
                           );
           }

         /* Join the terms, separating them with a comma. */
         echo join( ', ', $out );
        }

  break;        

 }
}






function mmd_track_emptytrash($post_ID)
{
if(get_post_status( $post_id ) === 'trash') 
  ClearMemberWorkouts($post_ID);

return 0;       
}
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'mmd_track_emptytrash');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  If a list is trashed, make sure all the list records are
//  removed from the table.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function mmd_track_place_in_trash($post_ID)
{
}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'mmd_track_place_in_trash');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue looks to be associated with your `mmd_member_track_columns_head()` function. Instead of modifying the default columns, they are being completely overwritten, causing the Quick Edit functionality to stop working. In particular, the `title` key must be part of the array for it to work. Try something like this:

```php
add_filter('manage_mmdtrack_posts_columns', 'mmd_member_track_columns_head');
function mmd_member_track_columns_head( $defaults ) {

    // Modify the existing columns, instead of overwriting them.
    $defaults['title']                             = 'Name';
    $defaults['mmd_member_tracking_workout_count'] = 'Number of Workouts';
    $defaults['mmd_member_memberships']            = 'Active Membershps';

    // Remove the "Date" column if you don't want it.
    unset( $defaults['date'] );

    return $defaults;
}
```

This code does a few things:

1. It retains the "Title" column to allow the Quick Edit functionality to work, but renames it to "Name". This should also allow you to remove code for outputting the title from `mmd_track_columns_content()` since WordPress does this automatically.
2. It removes the need for the `mmd_member_category` column, since WordPress outputs the associated taxonomy terms automatically. This should also allow you to remove code from `mmd_track_columns_content()`.

In general, I'd recommend using the functionality that WordPress already provides instead of rewriting it. Not only will this limit the amount of custom code you have to write, but it will also further ensure compatibility with future versions of WordPress.

I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Bingo!  I was overwriting the "title".  when I restored that, it is now working.  Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'm happy to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jg314, the answer was simple.  I took away the default Title  Once that was restored, everything worked again.

WRONG WAY. Remove this `$new_columns['mmd_member_name']` as seen below

```
function mmd_member_track_columns_head($defaults) {

    $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_name']                    = 'Name';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_tracking_workout_count']  = 'Number of Workouts';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_memberships']             = 'Active Membershps';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_category']                = 'Categories';

    return $new_columns;
}

add_action('manage_mmdtrack_posts_custom_column', 'mmd_track_columns_content', 10, 2);
function mmd_track_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID)
{
```

and the remove the associated key `case 'mmd_member_name':`

```
switch($column_name)
 {  
  case 'mmd_member_name': 
      $Name  = get_the_title( $post_ID );
      echo $Name;
  break;

  case 'mmd_member_tracking_workout_count':
     $user_ID = mmd_track_FindUser($post_ID);
     echo mmd_track_GetWorkoutCnt($user_ID);
  break;

   case 'mmd_member_memberships':
     $user_ID = mmd_track_FindUser($post_ID);
     if($user_ID==0)
       echo "None";
  break;

  case 'mmd_member_category':
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_ID, 'mmdtrack_cat' );

    /* If terms were found. */
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) 
        {
        $out = array();

        /* Loop through each term, linking to the 'edit posts' page for the specific term. */
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
           {
           $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => 'mmdtrack', 'mmdtrack_cat' => $term->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
                    esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'mmdtrack_cat', 'display' ) )
                           );
           }

         /* Join the terms, separating them with a comma. */
         echo join( ', ', $out );
        }

  break;        

 }
}
```

WHAT FIXED IT.  Add back `$new_columns['title']  = __('Title');`

````
add_filter('manage_mmdclienttrack_posts_columns', 'mmd_member_track_columns_head');
function mmd_member_track_columns_head($defaults) {

    $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';
    $new_columns['title']                             = __('Title');
    $new_columns['mmd_member_tracking_workout_count']  = 'Number of Workouts';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_memberships']             = 'Active Membershps';
    $new_columns['mmd_member_category']                = 'Categories';

    return $new_columns;
}
```
````